# leafletjs - emulate/fire a click onto 'mymap'

Tags: javascript, leaflet

hopefully an easy one!

After a form is submitted, I would like to emulate a click event on:

1. Map layer: 'layerWardDev'
2. Co-ordinates: '51.507, -0.127'
3. For the map: 'mymap'

I currently have the following code which returns an object:

`layerWardDev.fire('click',{lat: 51.507, lng: -0.127})`

However, the click is not working / triggering the popup / various other event listeners that rely on it. Am I missing something simple?
Thanks!

Comment: Those event listeners should be listening on the `mymap` object, not on your layer. Does `mymap.fire('click', ...)` work?

Comment: @Kvothe thanks for the response, but sadly no that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

The data for a click event should be a `MouseEvent` - so

```
layerWardDev.fire('click',{ latlng: ([51.507, -0.127])});
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's really depends on which layers you want to use (which popups).

Assumption 1 : we have markers A on the top of our MapDev

What we can do is to : select the marker per his ID (exemple A[i]),
A[i].fire('click'); and the popup is already defined for click event.

Assumption 2 : The popup is on the top of the map directly
we can open a popup directly without emulating the click event :

```html
  L.popup()
    .setLatLng([51.507, -0.127])
    .setContent('Test')
    .openOn(mymap);
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the click event triggers other event listeners that populate other parts of the data so sadly although this would create a popup, it's actually the other event listeners to populate a dashboard that I'm trying to trigger (based off of that click event)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not an exact fix... I iterated over each Layer with .eachLayer() and clicked the map manually for each.

The other thing I have decided to use instead is the .featureGroup which I think provides a richer functionality than layerGroups